# Where does pip3 install package binaries?

Tags: python, pip

It see that depending on system and configuration, packages are installed in different places.

Example:
Machine 1:

```
pip3 install fb-idb 
pip3 show fb-idb
> ...
> /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages
```

Machine 2:

```
pip3 install fb-idb 
pip3 show fb-idb
> ...
> /us/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
```

Now the problem I have is that on machine 1, I got the path to the binary by executing
`which idb` (> /opt/homebrew/bin/idb), but on machine 2, it seems the bin dir wasn't added to the path, so `which` doesn't work.

Is there a way to figure out where the binaries are installed, if I only have the site-packages path?

Comment: Why are you asking this? What are you trying to do? The paths you posted either show different OSs (MacOS and Linux) or different installation methods (HomeBrew vs native/direct install). You'll get even more paths if you use virtual environments to isolate projects

Comment: I need to find the executable, so I can start it (programmatically).

Comment: In python you could do `import fbidb;fbidb.__file__` and parse the path from that.

Comment: I think the approach must be a virtual environment always. You create a venv, then the packages are always inside that.

Comment: This still seems like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). If `pip` is correctly installed, it knows where to put the binary so that it appears in your `PATH`.

Comment: `pip3 show fb-idb | grep -F /bin/`

Comment: @phd does not work. pip3 show does not print the path to the bin folder

Comment: @stoefln I'm sorry, my bad, I've forgotten an important option: `pip3 show --files fb-idb | grep -F /bin/` . The directories are related to the header `Location:` so either `grep -F Location:` separately or do it combined: `pip3 show --files fb-idb | grep 'Location:\|/bin/'` .

Comment: Great, that's the answer @phd thanks a lot! If you post an answer I can upvote it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pip3 show --files fb-idb` shows where `pip` has installed all the files of the package. Run

```
pip3 show --files fb-idb | grep -F /bin/
```

to extract the directory where `pip` installed scripts and entry points (On Windows it's `\Scripts\`). The directories are related to the header `Location:` so either do `grep -F Location:` separately or do it combined:

```
pip3 show --files fb-idb | grep 'Location:\|/bin/'
```